# How to display a hidden inputfield with select

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-select

I'm trying to use select to display a hidden input field.  With option 2 I want to show the input field and with option 1 I want to hide it again.

Does anyone know what I need to change in the code?

Thanks in advance

```js
function showFooField() {
            document.getElementById("nameFoo").style.display = "block";
        }
```

```css
#nameFoo {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
 <select onchange="showFooField()" name="foo" id="foo" class="form-control">
             <option value="1" selected>1</option>
             <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
  
    <div id="nameFoo">
        <input id="name" required />
     <div>
```

Comment: You don't have any logic to check the option value or set `display="none";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not test the value before you changed the display.

I would use a class and toggle

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => { // when the page loads
  document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener("change", function() {
    document.getElementById("nameFoo").classList.toggle("hide", this.value === "1")
  })
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select name="foo" id="foo" class="form-control">
  <option value="1" selected>1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<div id="nameFoo" class="hide">
  <input id="name" required />
</div>
```

If you need to initialise:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => { // when the page loads
  const sel = document.getElementById("foo");
  const input = document.getElementById("nameFoo");
  const toggle = function() {
    input.classList.toggle("hide", sel.value === "1")
  }
  sel.addEventListener("change", toggle)
  toggle(); // initialise
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select name="foo" id="foo" class="form-control">
  <option value="1" selected>1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<div id="nameFoo" class="hide">
  <input id="name" required />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Run a check for the select value and you can manipulate the style from there

```js
const el = document.getElementById("foo");
const inputEl = document.getElementById("nameFoo");
el.addEventListener("change", function() {
  if (this.value === "1") {
    inputEl.style.display = "none";
  }
  else {
    inputEl.style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

```html
<select name="foo" id="foo" class="form-control">
  <option value="1" selected>1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<div id="nameFoo" style="display: none">
  <input id="name" required />
<div>
```